# Snowflake building step funnel

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, match-recognize

I have a table with 3 columns

1. USER_ID
2. EVENT_ID
3. EVENT_DATETIME

I am trying to figure out how can I write MATCH_RECOGNIZE so I can answer to following questions: How many distinct users interacted with event_id = 234, then during 10 minutes interacted with event = 444 then in 15 minutes interacted with event = 987.
One note here is that between events 234 and 444 user could have interacted with 50 different events that are not important here.

Comment: Please add some sample data with the desired results

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use MATCH_RECOGNIZE ? It would be much easier to just join 33 instances of the table